# return constant numbers over partition

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have the following table:

```
data = [(1, "user_1", 'foo.com'), (2, "user_1", 'foo.com'), (3, "user_1", 'bar.com'), (4, "user_1", 'foo.com')]
schema = ['event_actions_order', 'user_name', 'website']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show()

+-------------------+---------+---------+
|event_actions_order|user_name| website |
+-------------------+---------+---------+
|                  1|  user_1 | foo.com |
|                  2|  user_1 | foo.com |
|                  3|  user_1 | bar.com |
|                  4|  user_1 | foo.com |
+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

I want to be able to have a session number identifier each time a user move from one website to another website. I tried this:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('website').orderBy('event_actions_order')

df.select('event_actions_order', 'user_name', 'website').withColumn('test', row_number().over(w)).orderBy('event_actions_order').show()

+-------------------+---------+-------+----+
|event_actions_order|user_name|website|test|
+-------------------+---------+-------+----+
|                  1|   user_1|foo.com|   1|
|                  2|   user_1|foo.com|   2|
|                  3|   user_1|bar.com|   1|
|                  4|   user_1|foo.com|   3|
+-------------------+---------+-------+----+
```

but this is the output I'd like to have:

```
+-------------------+---------+-------+----+
|event_actions_order|user_name|website|test|
+-------------------+---------+-------+----+
|                  1|   user_1|foo.com|   1|
|                  2|   user_1|foo.com|   1|
|                  3|   user_1|bar.com|   2|
|                  4|   user_1|foo.com|   3|
+-------------------+---------+-------+----+
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lag` function to compare to the previous row in your window. Then you can do a rolling sum to get the desired restult

```
w = Window.partitionBy('user_name').orderBy('event_actions_order')

(df
  .withColumn('change', f.when(f.lag('website').over(w) == f.col('website'), 0).otherwise(1))
  .withColumn('test', f.sum('change').over(w))
  .drop('change')
).show()

+-------------------+---------+-------+----+                                    
|event_actions_order|user_name|website|test|
+-------------------+---------+-------+----+
|                  1|   user_1|foo.com|   1|
|                  2|   user_1|foo.com|   1|
|                  3|   user_1|bar.com|   2|
|                  4|   user_1|foo.com|   3|
+-------------------+---------+-------+----+
```